# How to get backBarButtonItem width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I try to get backBarButtonItem width:

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBtn = self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
UIView *view = [leftBtn valueForKey:@"view"];
CGFloat width;
if(view){
    width=view.frame.size.width;
}
NSLog(@"width %f", width);
```

but in console: `width 0.000000`

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? With `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` it's work.

Comment: Did you assign a custom view to backBarButtonItem?

Comment: No. I use default backButton from UINavigationController

Answer (score -1):

```
UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CALayer *btnLayer = [addButton layer];
        [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [btnLayer setCornerRadius:1.0f];
    [addButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 30)];
    [addButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [addButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    addButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Onclickevent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addButton];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

Comment: i know how to add custom button. I don't now how get frame.size.width from default backButton

Comment: Question is asking for the width of back bar button item.